# I retagged a snorkelling question as "diving" and just realized it - what would've been better though?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

The other day as I was doing my drive-by copyediting and tagging run I added the [diving](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diving) tag to [the question about snorkelling in Hawaii](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3036/what-are-the-most-diverse-places-to-go-snorkeling-in-hawaii-for-fish-and-coral/3056#3056) without apparently thinking it through properly because I've only spotted it now.

But is it a good thing or a bad thing? Technically snorkelling isn't really diving, but would a snorkelling tag just be adding something with not enough use and not enough differentiation?

Should we:

1. Just always tag snorkelling questions as "diving" for now?
2. Add a "snorkelling" tag as well as a diving tag?
3. Make "snorkelling" but add it as a synonym to "diving"?
4. Edit the name of the tag to something more inclusive like "diving-and-snorkelling"?

If we do go with option 3. I think we should edit the tag wiki/excerpt to specifically mention that it includes snorkelling.

Comment: Number 3, definitely. I think they have enough in common to justify lumping them together. And no. 4 is frankly an abomination.

Comment: Yeah I find it harder to avoid abomination tags on this SE than on any of the others I participate in. Perhaps due to being less sciency?

Comment: That's strange, I just noticed [a new snorkelling question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3221/snorkeling-in-southern-japan) and it seems to be the only one now with the snorkelling tag. How can this be?

Answer (score 1):

Posted separately as an answer since it's closely related but not the same.

We now have a "snorkeling" tag with one "l". I hadn't realized there are two spellings:

- [snorkelling](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snorkelling) (British and Commonwealth spelling)
- [snorkeling](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snorkeling) (USA)

I actually thought the British spelled tag already existed but it doesn't yet. In any case it's always a good idea to have these variants as synonyms. I believe the rule is the variant used in the Wikipedia article becomes the main synonym? As an Aussie of course I'm in favour of the "two l" spelling.

Comment: The two tags have been merged, [tag:snorkelling] is main tag.

Answer (score 0):

[snorkelliing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snorkelliing) should be a synonym of [diving](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diving), because I believe 'diving' covers all range of such water(sport) activities.

Vote up if you agree.